# How to apply Series.value_counts() on DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a DataFrame i would like to count the values of each column and use the values as index.

**I would like to turn this:**

```
Q1                   Q2                  Q3
Strongly agree       Agree               Undecided
Undecided            Agree               More or less disagree
Strongly agree       Agree               Undecided
Strongly agree       Strongly Disagree   Disagree
More or less agree   Undecided           Strongly disagree
```

**Into this:**

```
                        Q1  Q2  Q3
Strongly agree          3   0   0
Agree                   0   3   0
More or less agree      1   0   0
Undecided               1   1   2
More or less disagree   0   0   1
Disagree                0   0   1
Strongly disagree       0   1   1
```

How is this possible with pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on `value_counts`, you can use `stack` and `groupby` beforehand and then call `value_counts` before `unstacking`:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=[1]).value_counts().unstack(0, fill_value=0)

                       Q1  Q2  Q3
Agree                   0   3   0
Disagree                0   0   1
More or less agree      1   0   0
More or less disagree   0   0   1
Strongly Disagree       0   1   0
Strongly agree          3   0   0
Strongly disagree       0   0   1
Undecided               1   1   2
```

---

Another option is to use `melt` and `pivot_table`:

```
(df.melt()
   .pivot_table(columns='variable', index='value', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0))

variable               Q1  Q2  Q3
value                            
Agree                   0   3   0
Disagree                0   0   1
More or less agree      1   0   0
More or less disagree   0   0   1
Strongly Disagree       0   1   0
Strongly agree          3   0   0
Strongly disagree       0   0   1
Undecided               1   1   2
```

---

Solution using `crosstab`:

```
v = df.melt()
pd.crosstab(v['value'], v['variable'])

variable               Q1  Q2  Q3
value                            
Agree                   0   3   0
Disagree                0   0   1
More or less agree      1   0   0
More or less disagree   0   0   1
Strongly Disagree       0   1   0
Strongly agree          3   0   0
Strongly disagree       0   0   1
Undecided               1   1   2
```

Comment: @Hmmm I added a solution using `value_counts` (at the top of this post) if you're interested.

Comment: I think the stack way is preferable to melt, but not really sure why! (you can do level=1).

Comment: @AndyHayden Interesting. When I last compared them, `melt` seemed to have the edge over `stack`. Perhaps that could've been because of the overhead of constructing the multiIndex that `melt` did not do.

Comment: It's strange there isn't .value_counts on it, perhaps the apply is actually the best :) (May depend on number of columns/answers)

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the `pd.Series.value_counts` function to the whole dataframe and fill `NaN` values with 0.

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts,axis=0).fillna(0)
```